# Packing a .jar file with external files

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, resource-loading

I've recently finished a project I'm working on, and part of it involves using ImageIcons to fill JLabels.  So my question is about how I would go about making the filepaths more universal. By that I mean rather that having the path to my image being something like "C:/users/user/documents/project/file.jpg" for example.  I'm looking to pack it into a .jar file and include the target folders/files in a zip with the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Using Swing Components tutorial the [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) section shows seven scenarios in which the following code should works:

```
java.net.URL imageURL = myDemo.class.getResource("images/myImage.gif");
...
if (imageURL != null) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
}
```

Comment: To clarify further, you can store the image files inside a package, such as 
    `com.myapp.images`

You can then refer to them using 
    `getResource("com/myapp/images/img_1.gif")` 

and so on.

Note that the "." in the package name becomes a "/" when you want to load the resource.